# how to catch exit signal in asp.net core on linux?

Tags: c#, .net-core, async-await

I am writing a c# console app base on net core 3.1 linux

It was expected to

- run job async
- await job end
- catch the kill signal and do some clean job

here is my demo code:

```cs
namespace DeveloperHelper
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var http = new SimpleHttpServer();
            var t = http.RunAsync();
            Console.WriteLine("Now after http.RunAsync();");
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += (s, e) => {
                var ex = (Exception)e.ExceptionObject;
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                Environment.Exit(System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetHRForException(ex));
            };
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit +=  async (s, e) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("ProcessExit!");
                await Task.Delay(new TimeSpan(0,0,1));
                Console.WriteLine("ProcessExit! finished");
            };
            await Task.WhenAll(t);
        }
    }
    public class SimpleHttpServer
    {
        private readonly HttpListener _httpListener;
        public SimpleHttpServer()
        {
            _httpListener = new HttpListener();
            _httpListener.Prefixes.Add("http://127.0.0.1:5100/");
        }
        public async Task RunAsync()
        {
            _httpListener.Start();
            while (true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Now in  while (true)");
                var context = await _httpListener.GetContextAsync();
                var response = context.Response;

                const string rc = "{\"statusCode\":200, \"data\": true}";
                var rbs = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(rc);
                var st = response.OutputStream;

                response.ContentType = "application/json";
                response.StatusCode = 200;

                await st.WriteAsync(rbs, 0, rbs.Length);
                context.Response.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

expect it will print

```
Now in  while (true)
Now after http.RunAsync();
ProcessExit!
ProcessExit! finished
```

but it only output

```sh
$ dotnet run
Now in  while (true)
Now after http.RunAsync();
^C%
```

does the async/await block the kill signal to be watched by eventHandler?

the unexpected exception eventHandler do not have any output too.

is there any `signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, func)` in asp.net core?

Comment: Does this help? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.cancelkeypress?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: @Andy Thanks, after add `Console.CancelKeyPress += (s,e) => {...} `, ctrl+c will be catch by `Console.CancelKeyPress` and kill signal will be catch by `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit`. but the AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit does not await, it only print `ProcessExit!`, the output after await task.delay() does not print

Comment: I have one side question. Why are you using `HttpListener`? You are using .NET Core, why not use Kestrel and get a full blown web server that works much better? Here is an example of how to set it up: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48343672/1204153

Comment: I'll throw together an example of how to get everything to exit gracefully. I have a couple ideas.

Comment: @Andy  using a HttpListener simple open a port and ack request, by this simple impl of a web server, I can register an HTTP check to consul agent，thanks for your advice, I will look at it , do kestrel impl simple than(less code lines than) httplistener?

Comment: Way simpler -- you don't see `HttpListener` used much anymore because the Kestrel implementation is so well done.

Comment: @Andy another question, When use kestrel to impl a simple server,do   `applicationLifetime.ApplicationStarted/Stopped.Register(() => {}) ` works?.when I use it in asp.net mvc core, it seems works properly

Comment: @Andy `I have a couple ideas` waiting for you code sincerely

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, this may be a tad long winded, but here it goes.

The main issue here is `HttpListener.GetContextAsync()` does not support cancellation via `CancellationToken`. So it's tough to cancel this operation in a somewhat graceful manner. What we need to do is "fake" a cancellation.

Stephen Toub is a master in the `async`/`await` pattern. Luckily for us he wrote an article entitled *How do I cancel non-cancelable async operations?*. You can check it out [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/how-do-i-cancel-non-cancelable-async-operations/).

I don't believe in using the `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit` event. You can read up on why some folks try to avoid it.

I will use the [Console.CancelKeyPress](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.cancelkeypress?view=netcore-3.1) event though.

So, in the program file, I have set it up like this:

**Program.cs**

```
class Program
{
    private static readonly CancellationTokenSource _cancellationToken =
        new CancellationTokenSource();

    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var http = new SimpleHttpServer();
        var taskRunHttpServer = http.RunAsync(_cancellationToken.Token);
        Console.WriteLine("Now after http.RunAsync();");

        Console.CancelKeyPress += (s, e) =>
        {
            _cancellationToken.Cancel();
        };

        await taskRunHttpServer;

        Console.WriteLine("Program end");
    }
}
```

I took your code and added the `Console.CancelKeyPress` event and added a `CancellationTokenSource`. I also modified your `SimpleHttpServer.RunAsync()` method to accept a token from that source:

**SimpleHttpServer.cs**

```
public class SimpleHttpServer
{
    private readonly HttpListener _httpListener;
    public SimpleHttpServer()
    {
        _httpListener = new HttpListener();
        _httpListener.Prefixes.Add("http://127.0.0.1:5100/");
    }
    public async Task RunAsync(CancellationToken token)
    {
        try
        {
            _httpListener.Start();
            while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                // ...

                var context = await _httpListener.GetContextAsync().
                    WithCancellation(token);
                var response = context.Response;

                // ...
            }
        }
        catch(OperationCanceledException)
        {
            // we are going to ignore this and exit gracefully
        }
    }
}
```

Instead of looping on `true`, I now loop on the whether or not the token is signaled as cancelled or not.

Another thing that is quite odd about this is the addition of `WithCancellation` method to the `_httpListener.GetContextAsync()` line.

This code is from the Stephen Toub article above. I created a new file that is meant to hold extensions for tasks:

**TaskExtensions.cs**

```
public static class TaskExtensions
{
    public static async Task<T> WithCancellation<T>(
        this Task<T> task, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
        using (cancellationToken.Register(s => ((TaskCompletionSource<bool>)s).TrySetResult(true), tcs))
            if (task != await Task.WhenAny(task, tcs.Task))
                throw new OperationCanceledException(cancellationToken);
        return await task;
    }
}
```

I won't go in to much detail about how it works because the article above explains it just fine.

Now, when you catch the CTRL+C signal, the token is signaled to cancel which will throw a `OperationCanceledException` which breaks that loop. We catch it and toss it aside and exit.

If you want to continue to use `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit`, you can -- your choice.. just add the code inside of `Console.CancelKeyPress` in to that event.

The program will then exit gracefully... well, as gracefully as it can.

Comment: thanks. the `Console.CancelKeyPress` meant to catch ctrl+c, when the console app run in background with nohup, will need a graceful way to catch kill signal.

Comment: @Panic -- Check out: https://dejanstojanovic.net/aspnet/2018/june/clean-service-stop-on-linux-with-net-core-21/

Comment: and, I appreciate  to see the Kestrel implementation of this webserver with simple {"code":200, "data":200 } return